# Linking dependency

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic-linking

Start with shared library libA.so that is in /some/lib.
I build library (libB.so) that depends on a capability in libA.so. So, when creating libB.so, I include -L/some/lib -lA on the g++ command line.
libB.so will also reside in /some/lib.

Now, I'm building an executable that will use libB.so. I provide the expected -L/some/lib and -lB to the g++ linker. But I get an error because it can't find "libA.so". If I add "-lA" to the linker line, the program links.

I don't understand why it doesn't find "libA.so". I certainly don't understand why including "-lA" on the linker line lets it *find* it. It appears to already know that it needs libA.so, and libA.so is in the same path as libB.so.

Can someone explain this? I don't like the idea of having to explicitly put "-lA" in every executable that wants to link libB.so. Did I do something else wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you are linking against `libB` only, the linker looks for `libA`, but cannot find it, because it isn't in a findable path for the linker/loader. You have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (and/or `LD_RUN_PATH`) during the linking stage, or otherwise link `libB` with `-rpath /some/lib`.

Just pretend for a minute that `libB` is itself an executable, let's call it `foo`. You couldn't just say `./foo` at the command line because `libA`wouldn't be found (check `ldd foo` to examine the loader paths). Instead, you need

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some/lib ./foo
```

or you need to compile with `rpath`. (In `g++`, you'd say `g++ -Wl,-rpath,/some/lib ...` to pass the option to the linker.) The same load-time resolution process applies to dynamic libraries themselves.

Comment: Why does "-lA" put it in the findable path? It seems to me like "-lA" is putting it in the list of objects that need to be found, not path to find it in.

Comment: Let's take a simple program: When you say, `g++ -o foo foo.o -lA -L/some/lib`, the *linker* finds the library `libA`, but you still cannot *run* the program because the *loader* doesn't find it. You need to run the program like in my example, setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Don't confuse linking and loading!

Comment: If the final executable only use functions/classes from libB, why it still needs to link against libA? In windows you really don't have to.